# Integration testing of spree (alongside refinery)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rails-engines, refinerycms

I have just started a new rails app. So far there are no controllers or models there is simply the two engines: refinery and spree working next to each other.

They are mounted as following:

```
Store::Application.routes.draw do

  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/shop'
  mount Refinery::Core::Engine, :at => '/'

end
```

Now i have set up a few pages using refinery so when I go to / then i see the refinery home page and can click the about us page etc. When i go to /shop then i see the spree section of the site which is also working well.

Now i would like to write a small test that the spree engine is correctly mounted at '/shop'. I tried with the following test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SpreeEngineTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "has been correctly mounted" do
    get "/shop"
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

But it fails with the result:

```
Expected response to be a <:success>, but was <302>
```

I looked into the body of the request and it contains the following:

```
"<html><body>You are being <a href=\"http://www.example.com/refinery/users/register\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
```

I am using the standard testunit package and rails 3.2

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use assert_redirected_to instead of assert_response.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/ResponseAssertions.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. The reason is that Refinery will redirect you to the create user dialog when it detects that no users with the correct roles exists in the database. So my guess is that you're running this test without any users registered in the test database, and that causes the redirect.

In your integration test, add the following setup method:

```
def setup
  user = Refinery::User.new(:username => 'testuser', :email => 'test@example.com', :password => 'test', :password_confirmation => 'test')
  assert user.create_first
end
```

This will ensure that a default user with the right roles exist and the rest of the test should be ok.